# How can I multiply all the numbers from a list to display a new list?

Tags: python, list

Okay, this is really important and I just need someone to help me out. I'm very new to python so there are quite a few things I just can't get my head around.

I'm writing a program that asks the user to input a recipe name and the number of people that it serves.

Then, it asks the user to input information about the ingredients. I did this by creating a list, shown below.

```
ingredients = []
while True:
 ingredient_name = input("Name your ingredient: ")
 ingredient_quantity: int(input("Write the quantity of your ingredient: "))
 ingredient_unit = input("Write the unit of your ingredient: ")
 ingredients.append((ingredient_name, ingredient_quantity, ingredient_unit))

 cont = input("Continue adding ingredients? [y/n]")
 all_ingredients = " ".join(str(v) for v in ingredients)
 if not cont.lower() in ("y","yes"):
     break
```

The program then displays the list created. However, I then want to be able to ask the user to input a **new number of people** for the recipe, and then **multiply** the ingredient quantities of the list by this **new number**, to show a **new list** for the **new number of people**.

I have absolutely no idea how to do that so if someone could explain it would be so helpful to me! Also, sorry if this is vague or unclear, I've tried to explain it in the best way I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what list comprehensions were made for. Tuple unpacking is quite useful too.

```
new_ingredients = [(name, quantity*multiplier, unit) for name,quantity,unit in ingredients]
```